# Pyocr doesn't recognize get_available_languages

Tags: python, import, get, ocr

Im using Python and can't load languages from package pyocr.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import pyocr
from pyocr import builders
im=Image.open("Img1.gif")
tool=pyocr.get_available_tools()
lang = tool.get_available_languages()[0]
```

here I got "list object has no attribute 'get_available_languages'

Any ideas of how to solve it? I've never used pyocr.

Thanks

Comment: tool should be a list, but i get len(tool)=0

Answer (score 1):

The `tools` is a list, and you need to iterate over them;
the items are individual tools:

```
for tool in pyocr.get_available_tools():
    for lang in tool.get_available_languages():
        print("Tool {} supports language {}".format(tool, lang))
```

Alternatively, say you know you want to use `tesseract`, you can import it directly:

```
from pyocr import tesseract as tool
```

However the list of tools reflects the programs that are installed on the system; to enable the `tesseract` tool in `pyocr` you need to install the separate `tesseract` program. If it is found in the command path, the `get_available_tools()` will list tesseract. The other tool supported by `pyocr` is `cuneiform`.

Comment: yes, I know, the thing is that I don't get anything from the list. If I run len(tool) I get 0

Answer (score 0):

If `len(tool) == 0` (which you suggested in another comment), it means `tesseract` isn't on your `PATH`. In other words, if you can't run Tesseract from your shell, `PyOCR` won't find it either.

Comment: I can run from shell, but PyOCR just won't find it

Comment: PyOCR looks specifically for a command 'tesseract' on your PATH. Is it named 'tesseract' or has it any other name like 'tesseract-ocr' for instance ?